# How to modify regex to match in a sentence

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

How can I modify the `RegExp` to handle multiple words match in a sentence.

For example, right now it can match one word. If I enter `Ac` it will find it. But as in the fiddle example, if I type `Ag`, instead of showing the `AdidasAgain` box, it doesn't show anything.

I tried with `.` instead of `^`, now if I use `a` as a selection, it only shows `AdidasAgain` and `Azan`, but it should still show everything because they all have `a`

Comment: `var exp = new RegExp(value, 'ig');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `^` to `.*`. `^` means that it is the start of the line, where `.*` means any number of any characters.

Comment: perfect. Thank you. I almost had it :)

Comment: @Si8 Please mark this as the correct answer if it worked!

Comment: This will also give Adidas when entering 'di'. So a match with any substring counts. If this is what you wanted, then this is a correct answer. Actually, you can even omit the `.*`then.

Comment: @rplantiko Yes that is fine. I also +1 your post too because that works on a different scenario that I have. Thank you both.

Comment: One quick question what if the word is `Here We`. When I type `Here`, it displays correctly but when I type `Here W`, it disappears.

Comment: @Si8 In the JsFiddle you sent before, when you test it, you are splitting the text by a " ", then rejoining with "". So in this case, HereWe would be a match.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you are looking for matches with the *beginning* of words, please modify your code as follows:

- use the word boundary assertion `\b` instead of the begin assertion `^`
- don't strip the spaces from the spans' text content:

  ```
  $('#aSearch').keyup(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    var exp = new RegExp('\\b' + value, 'i');    
    $('.divA div').each(function() {
      var isMatch = exp.test($('span', this).text());
      $(this).toggle(isMatch);
    });
  });
  ```

Comment: You are quicker ;)

Comment: One quick question what if the word is `Here We`. When I type `Here`, it displays correctly but when I type `Here W`, it disappears.

Comment: With the keyup function given in my answer, it should work (don't have the link to your jsfiddle any more to check it): Observe that I removed your split/join operation on the text that you had originally.